# Magento : How do I create a module for Partial Payments?

Tags: magento, module, payment, checkout, partial

How do I create a module for **partial payments** ?.. means like client can pay Full or "50% now and 50% later". He should have the option at the time of checkout. Invoice will be created for the full amount but payment only 50%

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible and there is more than one way to do it.

I can suggest you the following solution for instance:

1. In case you are using a payment provider, you should modify its module in some way in order to take in account the 50% payment. For instance, an extra payment option should be created.
2. The remaining 50% should be persisted along with the order (custom order attribute)

However, keep in mind that in Magento, an order can only have 1 payment method.

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't do this out of the box.Implementing this is a lot of work, because you have to pay attention to a lot of things.For this one I would advice to look at the already existing extensions. First of all because since it's such a tricky thing to build yourself better get something that has been proven to work and second because they're not that expensive. Probably the hours you'll spent on building itself won't weigh up to the cost of the extension.

[Milople](https://www.milople.com/magento-extensions/partial-payment.html) offer an extension for this where it is possible to  pay Full or "50% now and 50% later".